# Why default flutter folder names lib?

Tags: flutter

Just interesting why is names `lib`. The Entry point is `main.dart`, so it's a little bit strange to see `main.dart` inside lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because when we code in Flutter, we're composing the widgets to make it functional & importable, thus we call it our `lib` (library).

Besides that, Dart is a new thing in this time, it surely unique from any other existing programming languages, so "little bit strange" is understatement. For example, we use `echo` to print text on the screen. Why "echo"? Isn't it supposed to outputting a voice? It was strange, but eventually people will adapt with it. Strange will not strange anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is not strange, lib is directory and this name is hardcoded and there is no way to change it. The whole pub package system depends on that directory name. There is also a convention that tools like the analyzer support code in lib/src being considered package-private when not exported by files in other directories in lib/.

The Entry point is main.dart but you can change main.dart(entry point) to some other page in Flutter.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the most anti-pattern thing i've seen in 24 years of development. It's nonintuitive, names and pattern is made for human... machines don't care if a directory name is src, lib, abc, xyz or 123.